# Get Google OAuth2 credentials or refresh token from Bearer type token?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am using python google api client library to handle an `id_token` of `token_type:"Bearer"` that it got from the front end using google's platform.js library.

The verification of the token is easily done by calling

```
google.oauth2.id_token.verify_oauth2_token(
  request.POST['bearer_token'],
  google.auth.transport.requests.Request(),
  client_id )
```

Now I want access to the user's google drive (full access). What I understand so far is that to build a service object we need a credentials object like so.

```
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

All I have at this point is a bearer token. How do I convert that into credentials so as to get access to the drive API?

Comment: My 2c. Stop using the library and call the endpoints directly. Your life will be much easier

Answer (score 3):

Credentials object came from "google.oauth2.credentials", to setting up your credentials object you need to know certain values:

- Token
- Refresh Token
- Token URI
- Client Id
- Client Secret

Here's how i get access to user's drive:

```
credentials = Credentials(
            token=token,
            refresh_token=refresh_token,
            token_uri="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token", 
            client_id=client_id,
            client_secret=client_secret,
        )

drive_service = build('drive', "v3", credentials=credentials)
```

You can try to set your "Bearer Token" as "Token", but i'm not sure if it will work. Here's the documentation of "Credential" object https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html

Comment: I don't have a refresh token from the user, only bearer token. Can you explain how to get the refresh token?

Comment: You can get the refresh token using "Flow" object, first you get url authorization using Flow.authorization_url(access_type="offlie",include_granted_scopes=SCOPES), this will return an "URI" and "STATE", after using the "URI" to get access to drive's user, you need to pass the full url to Flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=FULL_URL), after that you can get credentials using Flow.credentials.token and Flow.credentials.refresh_token